# How should I refer to static or client-side websites on a résumé?

Tags: resume, career-development, developer, websites

In my current job, I've built a number of static, mobile-first, single-page websites.

Generally, these sites embed event live streams from YouTube and highlight social media. These sites don't really render on the client (unless you count the `iframe` embeds) and I'm not using any particular frameworks to build them--sometimes not even jQuery. I'm sending mostly finished, plain ol' HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

So what do I call them on my résumé? Keep in mind that most reading it will be managers and marketers, not developers or engineers who know the lingo.

I dislike the terms "static website" or "flat pages" because they seem to imply something, well, stationary.

The terms "client-side website" and "single-page application" seem to imply more "app"-like functionality (and client-side rendering) than I'm providing.

A colleague suggested "micro-sites." The best I can come up with is "single-page sites." Otherwise, "static sites" seems to be the most used, and it's easily Google-able for anyone unfamiliar.

What do you think?

Comment: `dislike the terms "static website" or "flat pages" because they seem to imply something, well, stationary` ... but if this is the widely accepted term, then why not go with it ? If I'm in the know, it wouldn't matter what it sounds like to non-tech people.

Comment: And I'm assuming the resume will get passed on to technicaly folks to see iut

Comment: In this case, it'll be mostly "non-tech people" to review it and make decisions.

Comment: If I wanted to be precise, I would call them "static websites". That said, I could also use "websites" (as opposed to "webapps") or "HTML-only websites". "Single-page sites" or "micro-sites" seem unsuited for that. If you want it "dumbed down", maybe you could say "websites without databases", but I do not think it would be as clear as all of the above.

Comment: How about 'simple websites'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply list your role as a web developer and then explain what you did.  I would emphasize integration with Youtube and social media, and quick turn-around (if applicable)

E.g.

> Created event website that embedded you-tube feed, interfaced with company's FB, Twitter, etc, and made same day changes.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to not be specific off the bat on your resume. If you say "single page site" or "flat page" it could mislead the interviewer into thinking the wrong thing and costing you an opportunity.

Keep it simple. Put down something like "web development" and then list the languages/frameworks you know how to use under a skills section or in another area.

Your scenario is implying that the person reviewing your resume may not have a technological background. If that's the case THEY probably don't even know what they want when it comes to the terminology, so keep it simple and, as dishonest as it may seem, slightly vague. Don't lie, but don't box yourself into specifics that the reviewer won't recognize. When it comes time for the interview then you can feel free to elaborate and clarify.

Comment: Agreed. Keep the technical details to the technical interview. Remember that a resume is a tool to get past the first major filter in the hiring process - HR. The interviews are where you get into specifics, and which specifics depend on the type of interview.